# How to access multipart/form-data in Azure Function App function with node.js runtime

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, multipartform-data

I have an Azure Function App (Node.js) function setup with an HTTP trigger and I am trying to access the HTTP request file data but I am unable. There is an HTML form sending a POST request to the URL of my function on my local machine. This is the form:

```
<form
      type="multipart/form-data"
      action="http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1"
      method="POST"
    >
      <input type="file" name="file-one" />
      <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try as I may, the req.body and req.rawBody attributes of the "req" parameter to my HTTP trigger function only seem to contain a string with the name of the file and not any file data whatsoever. I cannot otherwise find any file data in the req object that gets passed to the HTTP trigger function. After reading up here and elsewhere, I really don't see an answer, everything I have tried so far has not worked. Short of passing the base64 file data in the JSON body, is there any way to just access the multipart/form-data file data from an HTTP request?

I found a guide on the internet that addressed this type of situation but their code indicated req.rawBody property would hold the unparsed data which does not seem to be correct. How do I access file data that is sent with the HTTP request in a Function App function?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to identify if the incoming request is a multipart request like - `req.headers["content-type"]` or if you've other way to do so.

Once you've identified that request is multipart/form data you can use libraries like [`parse-multipart-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart-data) or [Form-data-packages](https://npm.io/search/keyword:form-data) to parse raw multipart payload.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll set the header if I wind up needing to. Turns out though, I declared type="multipart/form-data" when it should be "enctype=...". Doah!!

Answer (score 0):

The form must have "enctype" set to "multipart/form-data" not "type". See below:

```
<form
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1"
  method="POST"
>
  <input type="file" name="file-one" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.